# Remove XML node when child node meets certain requirements

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml:

```
<listaGiros>

    <giro>
        <idGiro type="int">89</idGiro>
        <nombreGiro type="varchar">foo</nombreGiro>
    </giro>

    <giro>
        <idGiro type="int">78</idGiro>
        <nombreGiro type="varchar">apple</nombreGiro>
    </giro>

    <giro>
        <idGiro type="int">10</idGiro>
        <nombreGiro type="varchar"/>
    </giro>
</listaGiros>
```

which I want to become:

```
<listaGiros>

    <giro>
        <idGiro type="int">89</idGiro>
        <nombreGiro type="varchar">foo</nombreGiro>
    </giro>

    <giro>
        <idGiro type="int">78</idGiro>
        <nombreGiro type="varchar">apple</nombreGiro>
    </giro>

</listaGiros>
```

since I need to remove every `<giro>` node whose `<nombreGiro>` is empty

What's the best way to do it by using XSLT?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Use**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="giro[not(nombreGiro/text())]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<listaGiros>
    <giro>
        <idGiro type="int">89</idGiro>
        <nombreGiro type="varchar">foo</nombreGiro>
    </giro>
    <giro>
        <idGiro type="int">78</idGiro>
        <nombreGiro type="varchar">apple</nombreGiro>
    </giro>
    <giro>
        <idGiro type="int">10</idGiro>
        <nombreGiro type="varchar"/>
    </giro>
</listaGiros>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<listaGiros>
    <giro>
        <idGiro type="int">89</idGiro>
        <nombreGiro type="varchar">foo</nombreGiro>
    </giro>
    <giro>
        <idGiro type="int">78</idGiro>
        <nombreGiro type="varchar">apple</nombreGiro>
    </giro>
</listaGiros>
```

Comment: +1 Good answer. You could also use `<xsl:template match="giro[nombreGiro[not(node())]]"/>`